# CSS is not loading a local image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show image from my PC in my website using html file using css. The css, the image, and the html file are in the same directory the image is shown inside the web browser inspector as shown but not showing in the page it self  [Inspected Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bL8F.png)

```css
.logo {
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/100/100);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Waleed, you need to set some hight and with to your logo div try below code please..
`.logo {
  backgound: url(https://placekitten.com/100/100);
height : 100px;
width: 100px;
}`

Comment: thanks you a lot it worked like charm

Comment: welcome Waleed Ahmed!! can you please click flag and up-arrow if it's working..

Answer (score 2):

The div has no height — there is no explicit `height` in CSS and there is no content in normal flow to give it a height from the `height: auto` it gets by default.

Since it has no height, it is 0 pixels tall. Multiply the height by the width and you get a box that is 0 square pixels.

With a canvas size of 0, **there is no space to display the image on**.

Do *something* to give it a height.

```css
.logo {
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/100/100);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    Here is some content.
</div>
```

---

That said, a logo is something that conveys information. It isn't decorative. You should express it with HTML not CSS, and include [alt text](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html).

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Kitten Inc.">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry bro it didn't work with me however i tried your method without adding anything in the div and it loaded the pic normally

Answer (score 0):

The "logo" class must have a height in order to show its contents, you have several ways to set up the height:

### 01

inside your css, go to '.login' and between{ } write : height:100px;

result

```
.logo{
     height:100px
}
```

### 02

Inline like this

```
<div class="logo" style="height:100px"></div>
```

### 03

Using jQuery, like this

```
$('.logo').height(100);
```

or

```
$('.logo').css('height','100px');
```